# SwiftUI,Firebaseを連携したPDFの表示

Tags: firebase, swiftui

**実現したいこと**
Firebaseのstorageに保存しているPDFデータをswiftUIで表示する。
**問題**
Firebaseの通信やPDFDocumentは作成できるのに、PDFが画面に表示されない。

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import PDFKit

class PDFInfo_Mathmatics: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pageNo: Int = 1
    @Published var pdfView: PDFView = PDFView()
    @Published var stateTopButton: Bool = false
    
    func addObserver() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.pageChanged(_:)), name: Notification.Name.PDFViewPageChanged, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func pageChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
        pageNo = pdfView.currentPage!.pageRef!.pageNumber
        stateTopButton = pdfView.canGoToFirstPage
        print(self.pageNo)
        print("page is changed")
    }
    
}

struct ShowPDFView: View {
    @ObservedObject var pdfInfo: PDFInfo_Mathmatics
    
    var body: some View {
        PDFViewer(pdfInfo: pdfInfo)
    }
}

struct PDFViewer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var pdfInfo: PDFInfo_Mathmatics
    @ObservedObject var Firebase = firebase()
    @ObservedObject var pdfDocument = downloadImage()
    
    var url: URL {
        return Firebase.url ?? Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SampleData2", withExtension: "pdf")!
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFViewer>) -> PDFViewer.UIViewType {
        pdfInfo.pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfInfo.pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        pdfInfo.pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        pdfDocument.PDFdownload()
        pdfInfo.pdfView.document = pdfDocument.pdfDate
        return pdfInfo.pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFViewer>) {
    }
    
}

struct PdfInfoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var pdfInfo: PDFInfo_Mathmatics
    @State var enableTopButton: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text(String(pdfInfo.pageNo))
            // ボタンの状態を変えてクリック無効にする場合はこちら
            Button(action: {
                pdfInfo.pdfView.goToFirstPage(self)
            }, label: {
                Text("TOP")
            })
            .disabled(!pdfInfo.stateTopButton)
        }
    }
}


class downloadImage: ObservableObject{
    let PDFRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("MathmaticsSampleData/SampleData.pdf")

    @Published var pdfDate: PDFDocument = PDFDocument()
    
    func PDFdownload() {
        PDFRef.getData(maxSize: 82858620){date , error in
            if error != nil{
                print("error")
            }else{
                self.pdfDate = PDFDocument(data: date!)!
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct PDFTests6: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var object = downloadImage()
    @ObservedObject var pdfInfo: PDFInfo_Mathmatics = PDFInfo_Mathmatics()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ShowPDFView(pdfInfo: pdfInfo)
            PdfInfoView(pdfInfo: pdfInfo)
            .padding()
            Button("Tap me!"){
                self.object.PDFdownload()
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            pdfInfo.addObserver()
        }
    }
}

struct PDFTests6_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PDFTests6()
    }
}
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/352724) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ありがとうございます。今後気おつけたいと思います。